# Issues setting up and running an Angular 4 application without node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular

Currently, my web app consists of java with a html/css/js front end. I am trying to convert my application over to angular 4 while still using java instead of node.js/npm. This is my first time building an Angular 4 app and I am having some issues :( *"I've created tutorial/demo apps before but this is my first time converting an entire web app to Angular 4."*

I know that using node.js and npm is seen as the easy solution when working with Angular 4, but I need to use java instead of node.js/npm.

**The issue I'm having:**
I entered some sample code for Angular 4 into my application and when I attempt to build it using the "ng-install", I get a error that says "node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`".

I do not want to use node.js or npm in my project. Instead I want to keep using Java.

Does anyone have any examples or advice? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix up a couple of things: Java is the language which you use to build your backend. Do this, that's fine. JavaScript is language which is used for your frontend. Your problem is building the project. NPM is a package manager for JavaScript libraries. Even if you use NPM, it doesn't mean that you cannot use Java. Those are two different things.

Usually you would use Maven (or Gradle) to build your Java project and NPM or Bower to build your frontend. If you don't want to use NPM (because it needs NodeJS), you can use things like https://www.webjars.org. However, I would recommend to use NPM.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the quick response and help. 

I have the angular.js.min file in my project directory, isn't that essentially the same thing as using a webjar?

Comment: The Angular CLI is a NPM package itself. If you run "ng-install" you need NPM. Is there a reason for not using NodeJS/NPM?

Comment: I would prefer to not over complicate my project with Node.js - I have everything working with Java and without Angular, so, I figured it would be to make the transition over to Angular without using Node.